# Is there any way to setup permission for entire schema (entire tables) in Hasura graphql instead of giving permission to each table?

Tags: heroku, hasura

I want to give permission to entire schema in Hasura graphql (all tables). Is this possible to give permission to entire table instead of giving permission to one by one table. 
No access control rules in the table.
Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it from the web console. If you have a large amount of tables, perhaps it's worth to script it. You can introspect the tables from PG and then use Hasura's metadata API to setup the permissions.

[Metadata API](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/api-reference/schema-metadata-api/index.html#metadata-apis)